# How to request same parameter twice in query string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to request the following query string url: `api/item?name=storm&name=prest`

I am using the following code below and I cannot get the code to work.

```
public class ItemController : ApiController
{
    private cdwEntities db = new cdwEntities();

    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] Query query)
    {
        var data = db.database_ICs.AsQueryable();

        if (query.name != null)
        {
            **data = data.Where(c => c.Name.Split("&").Contains(query.name));**

        }
        if (query.id!= null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.ID== query.id);
        }

        if (!data.Any())
        {
            var message = string.Format("No data was found");
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
    }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use post Api and send array of [name].

```
 name = [item1,item2....]

 public void Post([FromBody] List<string> name) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass same name key in Querystring. Browser/Code did not identified which is correct value, if you want multiple value then pass as a object.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to clarify and ask, are you suggesting this functionality is not possible.